# How to filter RDD with sequence list in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi i am trying to filter rdd with dynamic in sequence in single statement so that filter can be applied

i have the rdd and list of restriction as below

```
    val contain_string = ("keymustexist1,alsokeyexmple2").split(",");

   var rdd2 = contain_string.map(each_value=>
     rdd.filter(l=>l.rdd.contains(each_value))
   )
```

Comment: You should do filter and in filter and do contains,rather than doing map and then filter

Answer (score 0):

[image: Wroks on spark-shell]You should do filter and in filter and do contains,rather than doing map and then filter.
Here is the code.

```
val contain_string = ("keymustexist1,alsokeyexmple2").split(",");
val lst = List("alsokeyexmple2","Hey","Hi")
val inputrdd = sc.parallelize(lst)
val op = inputrdd.filter(x => contain_string.contains(x)).collect
```

Comment: not working its return empty arry if i do the same thing with textfile

Comment: can you share sample textfile which you are using ?

Comment: INFO   PASS SET TempElement=877646,TESTBFunction=1,PKFDD=ICUB123 administrativeState SHUTTINGDOWN
INFO   FAIL SET TempElement=877646,TESTBFunction=1,PKFDD=ICUB123 administrativeState SHUTTINGDOWN  ---I AM TRYING THOSE LINE WHICH CONTAIN BOTH "PASS" AND "TempElement"